# How to fix overlapping x axis in box plot (SAS)?

Tags: plot, sas, overlap, box

I have been working with this annoying box plot for couple of DAYS!
This is SAS University edition.
Hope you could help me out unify same values in x axis.

```
proc import datafile="/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/chap1_3_97.xls"
                out=work.q01_01
                dbms=xls
                replace;
run;

libname mylib '/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/mylib';
data mylib.q01_01;
set q01_01;
run;

proc print data = mylib.q01_01;
run;

/* print box plot */
proc boxplot data=mylib.q01_01;
    plot smoking_rate * town_type ;
run;
```

I expect only two values in x axis: city and country. However, the actual output is loops of city and country.

[image: this is how the box plot printed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the BOXPLOT procedure wants the input data ordered by the grouping variable.  Try this example using a dataset that every SAS installation should have.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
  by sex;
run;
proc boxplot data=class;
  plot height * sex ;
run;
```

Or for your dataset:

```
proc sort data = mylib.q01_01 out=q01_01;
  by town_type;
run;

proc boxplot data=q01_01;
  plot smoking_rate * town_type ;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Tom,  I was totally lost with multiple x axis values. By grouping variable, it clearly worked. Thank  you so much!